# Split dataframe in R by date

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that contains one Date type variable. I want to export 4 files, one containing a subset corresponding to each week. The following will divide my data in 4 however I don't know how to store each of this in a new data.frame.

```
split(DataAir, sample(rep(1:4)))
```

Thanks

Comment: That line will create a list of 4 data.frames. So you are storing each in a new data.frame

Comment: If you save the split `s <- split(...`, you can then access each data.frame with `s[[1]]` and so on. To save `write.csv(s[[4]], ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your split data frames in a variable. You can access the elements with double-bracket subsetting, (e.g. `s[[1]]`). To save, create a vector of file names
as you'd like and write each to file.

```
s <- split(iris, iris$Species)
filenames <- paste0("my_path/file", 1:3, ".csv")
for(i in 1:length(s)) write.csv(s[[i]], filenames[i])
```

And for R users that get unnecessarily bugged out by for loops:

```
mapply(function(x,y) write.csv(x,y), s, filenames)
```